# filled antialiased poly cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can I draw filled poly in Cocos2D framework?

Code below draws poly but without antialiasing.What should I change?

```
void ccFillPoly( CGPoint *poli, int points, BOOL closePolygon )
{
    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, poli);
    if( closePolygon )
        //   glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, points);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points);
    else
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good approach to emulate antialiasing is to add transparent vertices around your polygon.
This method is fast and fine-looking, but is little hard to implement.
[Here is solution for antialiased lines](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1669-how-to-render-anti-aliased-lines-with-textures-in-ios-4/).

If you don't worry about performance, you may render the polygon multiple times with some transparency and offset by 1 pixel. This would work for not textured polygons.