# Draw filled dynamic polygon in Cocos2D, iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can i draw polygon with points read from NSMutableArray object in cocos2D framework?

I am able to draw polygon using this function: [filled antialiased poly cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257728/filled-antialiased-poly-cocos2d)

The problem is becouse points argument *(CGPoint *poli)* must be static object.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is type of `NSMutableArray` objects?
You need to extract raw data of points and set it as `poli` argument.
If it's `NSValue` with `CGPoint` then:

```
NSMutableArray* yourPointsArray;
...
CGPoint* poli = malloc (sizeof (CGPoint) * [yourPointsArray count]);
for (uint i=0; i<[yourPointsArray count]; i++)
{
    poli[i] = [[yourPointsArray objectAtIndex: i] CGPointValue];
}
ccFillPoly (poli, [yourPointsArray count], YES);
free (poly);
```