# is it possible for me to highlight the country area on Google map on searching specific country in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Basically i want to search specific country on MAPVIEW and then highlight the area of searched country. is it possible in iPhone app. this is the web link same thing implemented in asp
visit plz http://www.dyngeometry.com/web/WorldRegion.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to pay for it but dyngeometry has an API under the address
http://www.dyngeometry.com/WebServiceV2/GeometryInfo.asmx?op=GetCensusTract

If you query a city name as SOAP or HTTP(GET/POST) request they return you the coordinates with that you can draw your polygon on google map.

For drawing polygons you can refer to

[How to draw polygons with CGPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249683/how-to-draw-polygons-with-cgpath)

[filled antialiased poly cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9257728/859742)